# python maxTransform reduce time complexity

Tags: python, loops, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I have this function maxTransform.

**Psudo code provided to me**

Let A be a zero-indexed array of integers. For 0<=i<=j< length(A), let Ai..j denote the subarray of A from index i to index j, inclusive.

define the max transform of A as the array obtained by the following procedure:

Let B be a list, initially empty.

- For k from 0 to length(A)-1:

  - For i from 0 to length(A)-k-1:

    - let j=i+k
    - Append max(Ai..j) to the end of B.
- return B

The returned array is defined as the max transform of A. We denote it by S(A).
We need to find sum of S(S(A)). And if sum is very large, find it modulo 10^9+7

The correct code is given as per bellow.

```
#!/bin/python
import sys

def solve(A):
    #  Return the sum of S(S(A)) modulo 10^9+7.
    sa = maxTransform(A)
    #debug
    print ('sa = {} '.format(sa))
    #debug -ends
    ssa = maxTransform(sa)
    #debug
    print ('ssa = {} '.format(ssa))
    #debug -ends
    return sum(ssa)%(10**9+7)

def maxTransform(a):
    b=[]
    lenA = len(a)
    for k in range(0, len(a)):
        for i in range(0, len(a)-k):
            j=i+k
            #debug
            print ('k = {}, i={}, j = {}, a = {} '.format(k, i, j, max(a[i:j+1])))
            #debug -ends
            b.append(max(a[i:j+1]))
        #for i -ends
    #for k -ends
    return b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(raw_input().strip())
    a = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
    result = solve(a)

    print result
```

- **Right now its time complexity is O(n^2). I wish to reduce it.**
- Input Format:

  - The first line of input contains a single integer n denoting the length of A.
    -The second line contains n space-separated integers A0, A1.., An-1 denoting the elements of A.
  - Example: Input:

    `3
    3 2 1`
  - Output: `58`
  - Explanation:

    - We have

  `A = [3,2,1]
  S(A) = [3,2,1,3,2,3]
  S(S(A) = [3,2,1,3,2,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]`

  - Input constraints:
  - 1<=n<=2*10^5
  - 1<=Ai<=10^6

Comment: You haven't explained what the code is doing, which isn't obvious from the I/O format.

Comment: Yeah, actually it is implemented from pseudo code provided in a challenge. I am getting the given test output, but it is not working with very large input dataset. It is giving me time out.

Comment: No, you didn't understand. I'm saying that we need to know what the challenge is asking to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks for the comment. I have added the entire description in my code.